# Reading a csv with a very bad header

Tags: python, io, header

I am reading CSVs from files. I am having some trouble with bad headers.

Suppose I have:

```
CUSTOMER_NO;CASEWHENDWH_ADM.DIM_CUSTOMER_EXT.CUSTOMER_ACT_STATE='0'THENDECODE(DWH_ADM.DIM_CUSTOMER_EXT.CUSTOMER_STATE,'XX','UNKNOWN',DWH_ADM.DIM_CUSTOMER_EXT.CUSTOMER_STATE)ELSEDWH_ADM.DIM_CUSTOMER_EXT.CUSTOMER_ACT_STATEEND;CUSTOMER_ACT_ZIP;BIRTH_CITY;BIRTH_STATE;
5180222;RM;00034;COLLEFERRO;ITALIA;
4341121;RO;45027;TRECENTA;ITALIA
```

The `read_csv` function (`pandas` library) has some trouble in doing is job. I should say to the function:

> "Attention! Read the fields of the header as separated by ';'          "

.  Is there a way to do that (in the documentation I have not found anything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinks you can try [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

But instead of using its default delimiter ([,]) you can set the delimiter as ([;]) for your data.

Example code:

```
try (final CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"), ';', CSVParser.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER, CSVParser.NULL_CHARACTER))) {
    String [] nextLine;
    while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
        System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + "etc...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. I have already solved in the simplest way:

```
pandas.read_csv('myFile.csv', delimiter = ';')
```

That parameter works both for the file and for the header. I thought that the "comma separator" was the default but it probably is not.